# Use of Reponse.Write and <asp:>

Tags: asp.net

I try to use Response.Write to add the AccessDataSource and GridView logic.
But it does not work. Why?

I search  in Google, but few explanation was found. So how to use , please?

```
Sub doInquiry(ByVal sender As Object, _
                      ByVal e As EventArgs)

    Dim _div_1 As String = "<div style='position:absolute;top:180px;left:20px;width:1800px;'>"
    Dim _datasource As String = "<asp:AccessDataSource ID=""AccessDataSource1"" runat=""server"" DataFile=""~/App_Data/Northwind.MDB"" SelectCommand=""Select * FROM [Categories]""></asp:AccessDataSource>"
    Dim _gridview_1 As String = "<asp:GridView ID=""GridView1"" runat=""server"" AutoGenerateColumns=""False"" DataKeyNames=""CategoryID"" DataSourceID=""AccessDataSource1"" EnableModelValidation=""True"">"
    Dim _gridview_2 As String = " </asp:GridView>"
    Dim _tag_col_1 As String = "<Columns>"
    Dim _tag_col_2 As String = "</Columns>"
    Dim _field_1 As String = "<asp:BoundField DataField=""CategoryID"" HeaderText=""CategoryID"" InsertVisible=""False"" ReadOnly=""True"" SortExpression=""CategoryID"" />"
    Dim _field_2 As String = "<asp:BoundField DataField=""CategoryName"" HeaderText=""CategoryName"" SortExpression=""CategoryName"" />"
    Dim _field_3 As String = "<asp:BoundField DataField=""Description"" HeaderText=""Description"" SortExpression=""Description"" />"

    Dim _div_2 As String = "</div>"

    Dim combine As String = _div_1 & _datasource & _
   _gridview_1 & _tag_col_1 & _
    _field_1 & _field_2 & _field_3 & _
   _tag_col_2 & _gridview_2 & _div_2


    Response.Write(combine)



End Sub
```

Comment: For one thing, you're writing to an *HTTP* response, so including a data source--which is strictly for coding purposes (code behind)--won't do anything, and might cause errors. Start small by removing things and add some html or maybe a grid (i don't know if that even works).

Comment: You cant create dynamic asp controls like this